# Confused on sudo vs su and running scripts

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, su

When I do `sudo su - john` I become user `john`  **without** asking for a password.
But when I do: `sudo su - john /usr/share/script_to_run.pl` I am asked for a password.
Same also for `sudo -u john /usr/share/script_to_run.pl`

Why? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the content of the /etc/sudoers file; there is probably an entry reading something like: `user NOPASSWD: su - john`, which means that you can issue the command, but can't use parameters. This is more of a superuser question, though

Answer (score 1):

Now, first of all, the `-` means that you want a login shell. The first statement means that you want to, as root (hence the `sudo`), want to make it appear as you logged in as `john`. Somewhere it is configured that the user you are currently logged in as has the rights to do sudo without using a password.

What happens in the first instance is that you execute one command `su - john` (meaning "log me in as `john`), and you do that as root (since you put `sudo` first). Your current user has sudo-without-password-rights, and root has the right to become any user.

The second try is wrong. You can't use `su` to execute a command in that way, and when you want su to execute a single command, I see no reason to make it a login shell.

In the third option, you (as the currently logged in user) want to "become" `john` for one command. For that, you will need `john`s password. (When you do this as `root`, however, you don't need the password.)

To make it work you could probably try

```
sudo su --command="/usr/share/script_to_run.pl" john
```

or maybe even the more exotic looking

```
sudo sudo -u john /usr/share/script_to_run.pl
```

Comment: Both these options request me for password

Comment: Interesting. What user are you currently logged in as? What OS are you running?

Comment: I am logged in as user `george`.OS is centos

Answer (score 0):

"sudo" was designed to give all the functionality of "su", but not require them to use the other user's password. The answers you need are within the /etc/sudoers file, editable with the "sudo visudo" command. here you will find that you can make your user not require a password:

```
cratylus ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

thence submit queries with

```
sudo -u cratylus the statement
```

note: don't quote the statement - you only do this for the "su -c" command.